# Keras lstm with masking layer for variable-length inputs

Tags: python, keras, lstm, masking

I know this is a subject with a lot of questions but I couldn't find any solution to my problem.

I am training a LSTM network on variable-length inputs using a masking layer but it seems that it doesn't have any effect.

Input shape (100, 362, 24) with 362 being the maximum sequence lenght, 24 the number of features and 100 the number of samples (divided 75 train / 25 valid).

Output shape (100, 362, 1) transformed later to (100, 362 - N, 1).

Here is the code for my network:

```
from keras import Sequential
from keras.layers import Embedding, Masking, LSTM, Lambda
import keras.backend as K


#                          O O O
#   example for N:3        | | |
#                    O O O O O O
#                    | | | | | | 
#                    O O O O O O

N = 5
y= y[:,N:,:]

x_train = x[:75]
x_test = x[75:]
y_train = y[:75]
y_test = y[75:]

model = Sequential()
model.add(Masking(mask_value=0., input_shape=(timesteps, features)))
model.add(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(64, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(1, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Lambda(lambda x: x[:, N:, :]))

model.compile('adam', 'mae')

print(model.summary())
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, 
                    epochs=3, 
                    batch_size=15, 
                    validation_data=[x_test, y_test])
```

my data is padded at the end. example:

```
>> x_test[10,350]
array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
   0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)
```

The problem is that the mask layer seems to have no effect. I can see it with the loss value being printed during training which is equal to the one without mask I calculate after:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
masking_1 (Masking)          (None, 362, 24)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_1 (LSTM)                (None, 362, 128)          78336     
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_2 (LSTM)                (None, 362, 64)           49408     
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_3 (LSTM)                (None, 362, 1)            264       
_________________________________________________________________
lambda_1 (Lambda)            (None, 357, 1)            0         
=================================================================
Total params: 128,008
Trainable params: 128,008
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
Train on 75 samples, validate on 25 samples
Epoch 1/3
75/75 [==============================] - 8s 113ms/step - loss: 0.1711 - val_loss: 0.1814
Epoch 2/3
75/75 [==============================] - 5s 64ms/step - loss: 0.1591 - val_loss: 0.1307
Epoch 3/3
75/75 [==============================] - 5s 63ms/step - loss: 0.1057 - val_loss: 0.1034

>> from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error
>> out = model.predict(x_test, batch_size=1)
>> print('wo mask', mean_absolute_error(y_test.ravel(), out.ravel()))
>> print('w mask', mean_absolute_error(y_test[~(x_test[:,N:] == 0).all(axis=2)].ravel(), out[~(x_test[:,N:] == 0).all(axis=2)].ravel()))
wo mask 0.10343371
w mask 0.16236152
```

Futhermore, if I use nan value for the masked output values, I can see the nan being propagated during training (loss equals nan).

What am I missing to make the masking layer work as expected?

Comment: masking has some pretty serious issues in keras. Your data looks *post* padded here. Can you try the above with pre padding since your LSTM is going in the forward direction?

Comment: Not the root cause here, but the 'w mask' line is wrong. You're selecting the masked entries with `y_test[(x_test[:,N:] == 0).all(axis=2)]`.

Comment: Thank you for noticing the typo Yu-Yang, editing this and testing your answer :)

Comment: Is this by any chance the CMAPSSData?

Comment: There are three ways to introduce input masks in Keras models:
1. Add a `keras.layers.Masking` layer.
2. Configure a `keras.layers.Embedding` layer with mask_zero=True.
3. Pass a mask argument manually when calling layers that support this argument (e.g. RNN layers).
[Propagation a mask](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/understanding_masking_and_padding) to `Lambda` layer require a proper `mask` signature.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `Lambda` layer, by default, does not propagate masks. In other words, the mask tensor computed by the `Masking` layer is thrown away by the `Lambda` layer, and thus the `Masking` layer has no effect on the output loss.

If you want the `compute_mask` method of a `Lambda` layer to propagate previous mask, you have to provide the `mask` argument when the layer is created. As can be seen from the source code of `Lambda` layer,

```
def __init__(self, function, output_shape=None,
             mask=None, arguments=None, **kwargs):
    # ...
    if mask is not None:
        self.supports_masking = True
    self.mask = mask

# ...

def compute_mask(self, inputs, mask=None):
    if callable(self.mask):
        return self.mask(inputs, mask)
    return self.mask
```

Because the default value of `mask` is `None`, `compute_mask` returns `None` and the loss is not masked at all.

To fix the problem, since your `Lambda` layer itself does not introduce any additional masking, the `compute_mask` method should just return the mask from the previous layer (with appropriate slicing to match the output shape of the layer).

```
masking_func = lambda inputs, previous_mask: previous_mask[:, N:]
model = Sequential()
model.add(Masking(mask_value=0., input_shape=(timesteps, features)))
model.add(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(64, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(1, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Lambda(lambda x: x[:, N:, :], mask=masking_func))
```

Now you should be able to see the correct loss value.

```
>> model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
0.2660679519176483
>> out = model.predict(x_test)
>> print('wo mask', mean_absolute_error(y_test.ravel(), out.ravel()))
wo mask 0.26519736809498456
>> print('w mask', mean_absolute_error(y_test[~(x_test[:,N:] == 0).all(axis=2)].ravel(), out[~(x_test[:,N:] == 0).all(axis=2)].ravel()))
w mask 0.2660679670482195
```

Using NaN value for padding does not work because masking is done by multiplying the loss tensor with a binary mask (`0 * nan` is still `nan`, so the mean value would be `nan`).

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you very much for the complete answer. As can be seen in the masking layer doc [link](https://keras.io/layers/core/#masking), I was expecting an exception if lambda layer was guilty

Comment: @Yu-Yang May I ask what does the inputs do in the masking_func function. Meanwhile, what if the final Lambda layer doesn't make slicing operation? e.g., if I use Lambda(lambda x: x + 1), then the masking_func should be masking_func = lambda inputs, previous_mask: previous_mask, right?

Comment: @BsHe The `inputs` variable has no effect in this case. It is required only because in the `compute_mask()` method of the `Lambda` layer, the masking function is called with arguments `self.mask(inputs, mask)`. And yes, if the layer makes no slicing operation, then you can just return the `previous_mask` without changing it.

Comment: Does the Reshape layer propagate masks?