# How to deal with variable length sequences in keras for MLP?

Tags: python, arrays, keras, deep-learning

I am using Keras for implementing my MLP neural network architecture.

Suppose I have input_shape = (5000,8) for my architecture where columns 7 and 8 are simple integers (positive), but the problem is with these 6 columns. I want to give a numpy array having variable length to my model with padding value = 0 appended to each of these 5000 arrays (6 columns for every row till 5000) to make length fixed to 6. I want these '0' values to be non-trainable, i.e. I want my model to not to learn from these '0' (padding) values.

Input example:
pandas dataframe with 8 columns (0 to 5 for my array and 6 to 7 are simple positive integers) making 1st row like this:

[36,45,22,2,0,0,1,7], where these two '0' values that you can see in this array are used for padding purpose only while actual array is still [36,45,22,2].

I have read the below stack overflow question:

https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/48796/how-to-feed-lstm-with-different-input-array-sizes

where one of the answers showed me an example for 'Padding and Masking in keras' as follows:

In this approach, we pad the shorter sequences with a special value to be masked (skipped). For example, suppose each timestamp has dimension 2, and -10 is the special value, then

```
    X = [

      [[1,    1.1],
       [0.9, 0.95]],  # sequence 1 (2 timestamps)

      [[2,    2.2],
       [1.9, 1.95],
       [1.8, 1.85]],  # sequence 2 (3 timestamps)

    ]

    will be converted to

    X2 = [

      [[1,    1.1],
       [0.9, 0.95],
       [-10, -10]], # padded sequence 1 (3 timestamps)

      [[2,    2.2],
       [1.9, 1.95],
       [1.8, 1.85]], # sequence 2 (3 timestamps)
    ]
```

As you can see that this answer shows padding for the whole row means [-10, -10] has been added as new row for padding purpose only to array X2, but I want to pad 0 value in the same row as my example illustrated above.

How can I use Masking Layer of Keras for this type of scenario in order to not to make my model to learn from these padded irrelevant values? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you thought about creating and storing the masked arrays when you save the training data (as another data column in the HDF5 file)? That way you do the test once, and don't have to test again in Keras. Just grab the data and the mask. In your case Sequence 1 would have 4 True and 2 False, and Sequence 1 would have all 6 True. Alternately, you could save a field/column that tells the number of values to mask (assumes you always count from the end).